# how to design the code for catching a certain exception in a API interface util class

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I'm facing a problem that I need to add a handling for a certain exception when calling a third part API.
`ServiceUtilsHelper managers` the connection issue. `getAccesInterface()` return a `instance` which used to call the API like `getA(),getB()`.  What I want is adding a catch for a certain exception at calling `getA(), getB()` even more `getC()`.and try this call again. Problem is how to make the code keep clean?
thanks!

code piece:

```
public List<String> getA(Parameter arg) throws XXServiceException{

    return ServiceUtilsHelper.getAccessInterface().getA(arg);
}

public List<String> getB(Parameter arg) throws XXServiceException {

    return ServiceUtilsHelper.getAccessInterface().getB(arg);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by keeping code clean?

Comment: @Yang Li does [this](http://ankursinghal86.blogspot.in/2014/07/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc.html) help you

Comment: more for this, there's  public void dosomething() throws XXServiceException {}

Comment: I don't want to add catch exception in every method.  Do I have better choice?